# How do I remove an element in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I was wondering how to remove an element in selenium python, I'm wanting to remove a chatBox in a website like how you would if you manually did it by pressing backspace, but I want to do it in selenium. So far I've tried this

```
chatBox = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='chatContainer oldStyle']").remove()
```

This line of code gives the error

```
AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'remove'
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 7):

I found a solution to this, this is the code I used to fix it

```
        try:
            element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='chatContainer oldStyle']")
        driver.execute_script("""var element = arguments[0]; 
            element.parentNode.removeChild(element);""", element)
        except Exception:
            pass
```

Comment: Good you found it yourself, you indeed need a javascript to do that kind of thing (removing elements)

Answer (score 2):

You can use javascript to remove the element.

```
chatBox = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='chatContainer oldStyle']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].remove();", chatBox)
```